# Trigger MySQL with user

Tags: mysql, authentication, triggers

A friend of mine wants to do something with a MySQL DB, but I'm not able to help him.

He has an application which does something which I don't know, and stores the Windows login of the user as a varchar. Then, this application communicates with a MySQL database, and he wants to store (with a trigger, I think) the logs of actions done on the database, such as DELETE, UPDATE, ADD... But the problem is that he wants that any log indicates the Windows login of who did the action, and the action done.

If it's not very clear, don't hesitate to tell me.

Thank you very much. :)

Comment: what do you mean by windows login?

Comment: The login of the Windows session.

Comment: if you want to log logs of action on the database then you should create trigger on every table to store the action performed on the table.

Comment: I already know that, but I want to store the action plus the Windows login of the people who did it.

Comment: add more information to your question like db structure, code tried, etc.